# Angular app.component seems not connected with the app.module

Tags: angular

I'm setting up a basic Angular application with a `core` module contains `header` component and an `app` component which display a `title` ,including the `header` and, include a `router-outlet`.

`core/core.module.ts` :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      CoreModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

  export class AppModule { };
```

`app.routes.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  // Your routes here
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test-app';
}
```

And `app.component.html`

```html
<main>
  {{ title }}
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Unfortunately I have theses errors :

```
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:3:2:
      3 │   <app-header></app-header>
```

and

```
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:4:2:
      4 │   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
```

And in the browser console :

```
Error: NG0907: The _AppComponent component is not marked as standalone, but Angular expects to have a standalone component here. Please make sure the _AppComponent component has the `standalone: true flag in the decorator.
```

It looks like the component is rendered but it's not "connected" to the app module where Router and Header are imported.

EDIT : Project tree

```
app
|
|---core
|    |
|    |---components/header (basic component files)
|    |core.module.ts
|
|app.component.html
|app.component.scss
|app.component.ts
|app.module.ts
|app.config.ts
|app.route.ts
```

Comment: please share your project tree. as i see your project has configured as a standalone project and you are trying to use it based on modules.

Comment: @Mojtaba Nejad Poor Esmaeili
I'll add it. When I created the project all the components were standalone. But for project requireemnt I need to use modules and fit with this archi (core module, shared module and 1 module per "page/feature")

Comment: i think you are new in angular and you don't know how the module based and standalone projects work. in my opinion create a new project and don't use standalone architecture to use modules.

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili does it means I have to specify I want to use modules when I create my application with angular cli ?

Comment: ng new my-app --no-standalone

Answer (score 1):

Only the way the root component gets bootstrap has changed, you can still use modules, as shown in the below working example. Hope it helps!

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { routes } from '../routes';
import { CoreModule } from './core.module';
import { provideRouter, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CoreModule, RouterModule],
  template: `
    <main>
  {{ title }}
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
  `,
})
export class App {
  title = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)],
});
```

core.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [HeaderComponent],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-q8f8ve?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcore.module.ts,routes.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Do you mean the root component must not be part of a module but a standalone component ? Isn't it possile to have a root module ?

Comment: @nem0z due to the error you are getting that it must be a standalone, I'm suggesting this method where you won't get errors and you can still use modules

Comment: Well it seems that I did a mistake when creating my application so I'm working with a project that expect a standalone component as root. But to fit the requirement I'll create a new project and use modules this time. Thx

Comment: @nem0z ok All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this `core.module.ts`? As the error in the browser suggests, you can set up your `app-header` component to be a standalone component. By doing that, you will not need to use this `core.module.ts` anymore.

To setup your component to be a standalone, you just need to add the property `standalone: true` in your @Component decorator, and import the modules that your template are going to use, e.g.

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-header',
  imports: [CommonModule]
  ...})
```

Then you can import you standalone component in the `app.module.ts` instead of the `core.module.ts`. By doing so, you can simplify your code and maybe these errors will disappear.

For more information about standalone components, you can check here: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Comment: Use module architecture is a requirement for this project, maybe I did a mistake when initializing the project as all my components were standalone by default ?